# Is there any stretchy header framework for UICollectionView Flow not costum

Tags: uicollectionview

I found a couple examples that work but only with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Does anyone knows how to implement this with NO `UIcollectionViewFlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewFlowLayout is for showing the items in grid format.
You can use your custom layout inherited from UICollectionViewLayout and set it to collection view layout.

Even gallery implementation of the most of the apps is done using collectionview.